# VBA Excel - Deleting all entries of a row if certain cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to come up with a code that will delete all entries of a row if the corresponding B cell of the row is empty.

For example, if B4 is empty the code should delete all entries in C4:AU4. It should do this for all rows starting from B3 to a beforehand defined value for MaxRowList.

Only thing I could come up with so far is

```
Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

But this deletes the complete row from the worksheet which screws up the arrangement. It is essential that it only deletes the entries in the corresponding $C$:$AU$ rangeand doesn't remove the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Intersect` and `ClearContents`:

```
Sub tgr()

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Intersect(.Range("C:AU"), .Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to clear the content of the cells, not delete them (which would move to content of the cells below or to the right)?
Try

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = activesheet ' <== Replace with whatever sheet you are working.
Dim emptyCells As Range, cell As Range
Set emptyCells = ws.Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
For Each cell In emptyCells
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ws.Range("C" & cell.row & ":AE" & cell.row)
    r.Clear
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's possible to avoid a loop. Silly me, of course it is - see @tigeravatar.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, 1)
    r.Resize(, 45).Clearcontents
Next r

End Sub
```